# how to compare two hyper parameters in a hierarchical model?

Tags: hierarchical-data, hierarchical, mcmc, hyperparameters, rjags

In one hierarchical model, we have two hyer parameters: dnorm(`A_mu`, 0.25^-2) and dnorm (`B_mu`, 0.25^-2). In this case, 0.25 is the sd, I use the fixed number. `A_mu` and `B_mu` represent the mean of group level. After fitting the data by `rjags`, we get the distributions for each parameter. So I just directly compare the highest posterior density  interval (HDI) of  `A_mu` and `B_mu`? Do I need to calculate something using the sd(0.25)?

In another case, if  the sd of two hyper parameters is not fixed, like that: dnorm(`A_mu`, `A_sd`) and dnorm (`B_mu`, `B_sd`). How can I compare the two hyper parameters and make a decision, e.g. this group is significantly different another group?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you are getting posterior **distributions** for A_mu and B_mu. This makes your comparison easy as you can have a look at 95% confidence intervals (CI) for the parameters (or pick a confidence value that satisfies your needs). I believe JAGS uses Gibbs sampling and so you should be able to get the raw samples from the posteriors for A_mu and B_mu. You can then ask *"what is the probability that B_mu is greater than some value?"* by calculating the percentage of posterior samples that are greater than that value. Alternatively, and in a similar way to frequentist Hypothesis testing, you can ask what is the probability that the mean of B_mu is a draw from the posterior of A_mu. So the key is just to directly use the samples from your posterior. I would recommend taking a look at Andrew Gelman's BDA3 textbook (Chapter 4) for a really good reference on these concepts.

A few things to keep in mind before drawing conclusions from the data: (1) you should always check the validity of your Markov Chains by evaluating things like autocorrelation (2) try to do a posterior predictive check to make sure your model is well fit to the data. If your model is poorly fit to the data then you can get very misleading results from the procedure above.